# Custom Extension Adjustment to 6.2

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.7

I currently got the task to upgrade a custom made CRM extension named "kbs". It was developed on TYPO3 4.7 and using old namespaces in its classes like "Tx_Kbs_Service_TestService" etc.

I want to upgrade this whole extension to be able to work properly with our current backend version of 6.2. More specifically i want to be able to use the extension builder to make changes to this extension which i am currently not able to do on the 6.2 TYPO3 backend. It is not even an option to select the "kbs" extension in the extension builder.

Of course i reasearched the web but I find it very difficult to find information what you have to do in order to addapt a custom extension.
So far I assume that i will have to change all the namespaces in all my classes manually and maybe watch out for decrecated classes. But I do not really know if that is the way to go.

Does anyone have and guidelines, links or tipps for me? I would really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

To the first question:
In extension_builder only extensions are changeable, they had their original configuration made by extension_builder. 
Extension builder itself is only an option to use, and there were also other options to kickstart an extension.

**Update:**
This is true, that extension builder is not an "editor" for extensions but a tool to help kickstarting an extension.

If I would get the task and extension_builder would be available I would not use it to make changes on the code. **It is not 100% sure, that manually changes were not made on the code after its last automatically generated version.** And if dummy actions were changed and properly excluded from the config they could be also deleted.

I think your best choice to change the things manually.

There are two source to read first:

[TYPO3 6.2 Release Notes.](https://get.typo3.org/release-notes/6.x/TYPO3_CMS_6.2)

[What's new presentation (TYPO3 6.2)](https://typo3.org/download/release-notes/whats-new/)

They contains breaking changes and some example.

If you do not change the PHP version, than changing the Namespaces and some deprecated functions. (The sources above could help to get an idea on those) 
One tricky part could be to migrate old image logic into the "new" FAL (File Abstraction Layer). If you don't need to deal with images, then it must be an easier thing to go with.

There is also an extension to help with some migration stuff: smoothmigration.

You can find some hints in this presentation also: 
[jweiland: Smooth Migration TYPO3 4.5 > 6.2 LTS](https://jweiland.net/fileadmin/pdf/vortraege-praesentationen/upgrade-45_62-certifuncation.pdf)

Comment: You should emphasize that the extension-builder is no editor for extensions. It is a kickstarter for extbase(no pi_based!) extensions and can, with some preparations, enhance formerly created extensions - with the danger that added code might be overwritten if you are not carefully.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ: I extended the answer. If you want you can extended it also with your thoughts!

Comment: I do not quite understand why using the extension builder is frowned upon?
On the "old" not upgraded system we use it to create plugins, extend classes with new methods or insert new classes. They also get generated in the database in the current structure we need.

Of course it could overwrite code but we have set times to do updates which does not interfere with anyones work.

What else do you recommend? Should i do all the Tables, Classes etc. manually? It seems alot slower.

Comment: @SimonNom: I used extension builder to quickly draw structures, it has some nice features, but I am a fan to buiding TCA manually, because with the version changes I saw some "deprecation" in the generated code. Getting a schema quickly into the code is also a feature from an IDE, so on a longterm you can configure it as well. Anyway if you have set up a process already on the extension builder then it is a working usecase. But unrotunatelly if the extension was already built, it won't be a help. Except if you start again from scratch and after the modelling you copy the functionality.